# Force the terminal output buffer to flush

Tags: macos, terminal, d

Writing a CLI tool in D, I have a progress counter, which is a loop, and print the next number preceded with a \r.

Here is a minimal example that shows the problem

```
import std.stdio;
import core.thread;

void main(string[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        write("\r", i);
        Thread.sleep(msecs(1));
    }
}
```

I have noticed that, at least the mac terminal, buffers the output, which is flushed once a newline is printed, or a certain amount of characters has been printed.

For me, this means that the counter laggy and sporadically goes up.

My question is,
How do I force flush the output buffer, without printing a newline?

Comment: Be more specific: what language are you writing your program in? Could you show us some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'clearing the buffer' you probably mean flushing. `stdout.flush;` should do the trick.

Clearing normally refers to removing all output from the console to get a clean window.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [weltensturm's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1634531/weltensturm) answer to call `stdout.flush` periodically, you may try to manually set buffering with

```
  stdout.setvbuf(0, _IOLBF);
```

See [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 - setvbuf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) (or your local manpages) for an overview.